# Does it violate App Store/YouTube TOS to develop YouTube Player app?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, development, youtube

I want to develop a 3rd party YouTube Player app which only have 2 main features:

1. Background playback
2. Block ads

If I submitted this app to App Store. Will Apple approve my app? Does that violate App Store or YouTube Terms of Service? I know that downloading of YouTube videos in a client app is prohibited, but I'm not sure about background playback and ad blocking. I saw some apps have those features and currently available on App Store and some were removed from the App Store.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What kind of background playback capabilities are you looking for? Do you want to implement [PIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_standard_player) playback mode or you wish to keep the playback running to hear the audio while the app is executing in background?

Comment: Keep the playback running to hear the audio while the app is executing in background?.

Comment: That's something that Apple won't allow. Background executing of video (without PIP mode) is not something that you can do and get it approved by Apple for App Store.

Comment: But, some apps on App Store has that feature. (For example : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-player-for-youtube/id1058774427?mt=8)

Comment: That app apparently is using background audio playback permission, not video.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean background audio playback not a video.